# Cambiar el valor de un placeholder de Stripe Laravel Cashier

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, stripe

Bueno estoy creando un formulario con la pasarela de pago Stripe en laravel lleva el nombre como Laravel Cashier, y el punto es que en el formulario hay un `input text`, que tiene un placeholder con lo siguiente: '*Número de Tarjeta*' es correcto pero lo quiero cambiar al Inglés, y es que por Default el resto viene en Inglés solo ese se puso en Español.

Lo tengo en mi vista blade, el punto es que se carga en un div(**card-element**) todo ese contenido, y solo con el inspector de elementos tengo acceso a ver los nodos del HTML:

**Blade view:**

```
<input id="card-holder-name" type="text">

<!-- Aquí carga todo el formulario -->
<div id="card-element"></div>

<button id="card-button" data-secret="{{ $intent->client_secret }}">
    Update
```

**Payment Method**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y bueno como pueden ver no tengo acceso desde mi HTML, todo esta concentrado en ese div, y dentro ese esta un iframe;
Acá adjunto esta imagen, del HTML examinado con el inspector, trate de copiar el código dando ver código de fuente, pero no se muestra el contenido;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es debido a que [Stripe Elements](https://stripe.com/payments/elements) toma el lenguaje preferido de tu navegador. Si el lenguaje de tu navegador es inglés, entonces el campo aparecerá en inglés.

Comment: Vaya amigo no tenía idea, por un momento pensé que usaba un JSON para traducir, hice la prueba en otro navegador y configure el idioma en Inglés y efectivamente cambio en automático el placeholder, vaya gracias!!